# Executing a batch file containing an exe path remotely via wmic

Tags: wmi

I have a batch file on Computer-A that contains several commands and a path to an exe file.

When I execute the batch file on Computer-B via wmic, I can see all the commands being executed in the batch file except that it does not run the exe. What are the things I need to check for to see why the .exe is not being executed on Computer-A?

wmic execution:

```
wmic /node:"<server_ip>" /user:domain\user /PASSWORD:"password" /OUTPUT:STDOUT process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\Folder\batch.bat"
```

Comment: Could it be UAC?

Comment: I am able to run the batch file locally on Computer-A. I don't think its UAC in that case.

Comment: I think it is not possible to remotely execute interactive processes via wmic due to security reasons.